# Multiple errors when trying to validate app before submitting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to validate my app, but getting the errors in the image.

In Itunes Connect I have:

Bundle ID: phil.quotes

The error messages are very specific and all came at once, though I have only trying changing the field 'bundle identifier' under 'info' in Xcode

[image]

Comment: Check your bundle identifier

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, because the result of apple has given you, you have signed an application tied to another bundle identifier. Go to your project properties, check the bundle identifier and the most important, the distribution certificate you have created. They should match. I dont know if you are resigning the application or changing the bundle identifier. Some people do that in some companies when you submit an app : you send the ipa and then they change the bundle identifier (which is unique for every app) and resign the application with their own certificates. Check that and try again, it should work.

Comment: I ended up adding a new app in Itunes Connect and changing to the correct Bundle Identifier - which solved the issue. Very basic thing to miss.